# Languages with only a gender-neutral word for aunt/uncle

Tags: list-of-languages, gender

English has the words *brother* and *sister*, but then we also have the word *sibling* as a gender-neutral version. We have the words *aunt* and *uncle* as well, but no gender-neutral version. What languages have such a word? Are there any that have such a word and *don't* have gender-specific options at all?

Comment: In **Spanish**, *Los tíos* could mean either "uncles" or "aunts and uncles" (in any combination). Note, however, that *Las tías* can only mean "aunts". I'm not sure if this qualifies your requirements.

Comment: Also, [there are languages](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/15685/1009) that have **four** words for "uncle/aunt". :-)

Comment: @bytebuster: The same is true in Portuguese and I believe Italian. Likely some other Romance languages as well.

Comment: @Bytebuster: but that is because the masculine gender traditionally subsumes the feminine in a plural. That doesn't give a word that means a (singular) uncle or aunt.

Comment: @bytebuster Standard Mandarin has at least **fourteen** different words for ‘uncle/aunt’ (if you include your parents’ siblings’ spouses as being ‘uncles’ and ‘aunts’).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll offer that in **Khmer** there is only a gender-neutral term for *older* siblings of your parents, អ៊ុំ /ʔom/. The terms for younger siblings of your parents are gender-specific, មីង /miːŋ/ for females and ពូ /puː/ for males.

Like the [Thai example](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/is-honorific-uncle-common-across-the-languages-of-the-world?lq=1) cited in the comments, these are honorific terms not restricted to family, however unlike Thai, there is no general distinction between paternal and maternal aunts and uncles. For more information on Khmer honorifics, here is a decent [blog post](http://www.banyanblog.com/home/hierarchy-in-khmer-language) on the subject.